# How can I make a Progress bar effect by click on a label

Tags: swift

I want to add progress to my progress bar after a click action on a label.
I imagine it would be similar to when you for example change a label's text like:

```
label.text = "example"
```

Then I imagined there must be some option similar to the progressbar?
this is just my imaginary example of what I thought it might be?

```
 progressbar.progress = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out it actually was thenameofyourbar.progress = the value

However, I had to be a float! that was my mistake!